# JQuery plugin Chosen not working in my Ionic app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ionic-framework

I am using JQuery plugin CHOSEN for multiple select. However it is not working. It is not creating a drop down list and the options are visible and even can not select them.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

</head>
</html>
```

chosen.html code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
</script>
</head>

<ion-view view-title="Profile">
<ion-content class="padding">

<div>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <div class="input-label">Enter Your Option</div>
            <select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="faculty" style="width:1000px;">
                <option value="Option 2.1">Option 2.1</option>
                <option value="Option 2.2">Option 2.2</option>
                <option value="Option 2.3">Option 2.3</option>
            </select>   
    </label>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for an error message? It looks like you're not loading the scripts in the second file

Comment: yes checked the console for errors but no errors..

Comment: how to load scripts in the 2nd page?

Comment: Where is the `chzn-select` class?

Comment: edited my code now..

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency is not following order. let `X` plugin depend on `y` so `y` plugin should be added first .so possible order is

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

check the dependency of for more details ordering

Comment: `<script src="js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>` has some confusion.find out which one is dependent on what

Comment: Can you paste the Console result of firebug

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code and done this on local machine.Try this it works

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="plugin_CHOSEN.aspx.cs" Inherits="DATATABLE_plugin_CHOSEN" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="prism.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="prism.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

<ion-view view-title="Profile">
<ion-content class="padding">

<div>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <div class="input-label">Enter Your Option</div>
            <select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="faculty" style="width:1000px;">
                <option value="Option 2.1">Option 2.1</option>
                <option value="Option 2.2">Option 2.2</option>
                <option value="Option 2.3">Option 2.3</option>
            </select>   
    </label>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All file on all same folder .i download all file from this link
[Chosen download Link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

**See the order.Its important for plugin to work**

Comment: what is in prism.js ?

Comment: It is a dependency of CHOSEN for dynamic functionality .download chosen with above link ,get prism.js and add this dependency to work with chosen